# Google Cloud SQL import size bigger than original DB

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I'm confronting a strange situation here with Google Cloud SQL.

I'm migrating a 15.7Gb mysql database to Google cloud. I've followed the migration process exactly as the doc says. And everything worked perfectly. Absolutely no issue during the process, my application works just fine. The only problem here is that the size used by the DB shown on Google Cloud is much bigger that the original DB. Right now I have a 39Gb sql database, from a 15.7Gb database.

After some research and testing I've come to the conclusion that it's the way that Google count the data on their side.

I just wanted to know if somebody have any idea, or can confirm what I'm saying.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: How were you calculating your database side before migrating? If you were just counting the sql dump that you used to migrate instead of the actual data on the file system, then that could account for the discrepancy, especially if you make heavy use of indexing.

Comment: Thank you for your response @JNevill

Exactly!
Actually my source database is hosted on Rackspace and I can't connect to the system and see how much space is been used. The interface tell me that's 15.7Gb is been used. And there's nothing telling me how they count it.

What I did to do some investigation is that I've calculated the space used through a mysql query and in that case. Both space in the source and Google cloud destination are pretty much the same for that reason I want to say that case closed.

Comment: That's interesting that rackspace's reporting of the database size would be so different since they would both be interested in the physical space on the disk (I would guess). Strangeness.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Can't complain if the bill come smaller but as I'm seeing the pricing calculation is a bit different between both providers.

Comment: Do you have binary logs enabled on Rackspace? They are enabled by default for Cloud SQL and they will take up a lot of space during the initial import since a lot of data is being changed. The usage will go down after 7 days when the logs are pruned (assuming you don't have anything else that is growing them significantly). You can always turn off binary logs if you don't need them. (Disabling/re-enabling them will also prune them).

Comment: That's it! Thank you @Vadim. The database got significantly reduced after following your steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Vadim.

The huge database size was due to the binary logs option that was enabled by default on Google Cloud SQL.

I've pruned them by disabling and re-enabling the binary logs option. The database got from 39Gb to 24Gb.